# Is there a way to operate macro to all markers?

Tags: vim, neovim

For example if a use `ma` `mb` etc to create some markers in buffer. Then i record a macro, then i want to execute macro to all these markers, how can i do to accomplish this goal

Maybe it can be completed by writing a function by `lua` or `viml`, or use some plugins or just a vim command is all accepted. I'd like someone can give a example function to make me learn more about neovim or vim

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I try the `getpos` function and write a person function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getpos("'".mark_name)` to obtain the position of a *mark*. And a macro can be executed with `exe 'normal @'.macro_name`.

Which gives:

```
function! s:exec(macro, marks) abort
  for mark in split(a:marks, '\zs\ze')
    call setpos('.', getpos("'".mark))
    exe 'normal @'.a:macro
  endfor
endfunction

command! -nargs=+ RunMacroOnMarks  call s:exec(<f-args>)
```

Then if you've recorded a macro in register `m` and marked two positions `a` and `b`, it can be used with:

```
:RunMacroOnMarks m ab
```

Note: I've chosen to be explicit with the list of marks as we are likely to want to restrict the macro to a very limited number of registered positions.

Answer (score 0):

I use [marks.nvim](https://github.com/chentoast/marks.nvim) to accomplish this.

then set keymap

```lua
local keymap = vim.api.nvim_set_keymap
keymap('n', '<leader>xx', '<Plug>(Marks-next)', { noremap = true, silent = true })
```

now you can combo with macro.

Comment: This plugin is great tks!!